# I'm having trouble getting scripts to run properly in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
function initialize() {
            //myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808,-122.0838851);

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 18,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.564613,-70.809087),
                // zoom: 5,
                // center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                  myOptions);

   geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                map: map,
                singleInfoWindow: true,
                afterParse: useTheData
            });
            geoXml.parse('ActivityStatus_Producing_labels.kml');
        };
function kmlClick(marker) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(geoXml.docs[0].markers[marker],"click");
}

function useTheData(doc){
  // Geodata handling goes here, using JSON properties of the doc object
 var sidebarHtml = "<table>";
 for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].markers.length; i++) {
 // console.log(doc[0].markers[i].title);
sidebarHtml += '<tr><td><a     href="javascript:kmlClick('+i+');">'+doc[0].placemarks[i].name+'</a></td></tr>';
  }
```

I am getting an error that doc[0].markers.length cannot get the length from a null or non existent variable depending on which browser I use.

In this website: http://thoughtfi.com/geoxmlpractice/practiceIMR2.html I can get it to run in Chrome but not IE

This website works in IE and Chrome and has almost the same code: http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_us_states_kml_test.html

How can I get my site to work? I'm guessing it's not parsing the kml file in time or the server/browser is too slow to parse the kml?

Comment: Function expressions like `function(){}` don't have a semicolon at the end. Also you seem to be missing a brace `}` at the end of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the kml file.  IE doesn't believe it is valid xml.  Neither does feedvalidator:
http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fthoughtfi.com%2Fgeoxmlpractice%2FActivityStatus_Producing_labels.kml#l675

If I fix the invalid xml (and the character encoding the xml file reports), it works for me:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/thoughtfi_com_geoxmlpractice_practiceIMR2a.html

[Here is another example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/ActivityStatus_Producing_labelsA_kml.xml) displaying the "fixed" kml

[You can also see what Google Maps thinks of your kml](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fthoughtfi.com%2Fgeoxmlpractice%2FActivityStatus_Producing_labels.kml&hl=en&sll=44.999706,45.000086&sspn=0.011805,0.01929&t=m&z=16):

> http://thoughtfi.com/geoxml... could not be displayed because it is not a valid KML or KMZ file.

Comment: sweet! I cant wait to try this tomorrow on a computer with IE

Comment: hmm, at the moment I'm having trouble getting this to work on chrome and firefox with this method. I basically have the same file except I save it as an xml. is there something I am missing?

Comment: I need to save it as xml on my server because my server is not configured to serve kml (you don't need to do that).  The xml content of your file was not valid, and IE(8) wouldn't successfully parse it.